# How to delete a Discord channel using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@Bot.command(pass_context= True)
async def complete(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    id_admin = discord.Role.id=658306078928273408
    overwrites = {
        id_admin: discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=True),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),

    }
    await guild.delete_text_channel(discord.TextChannel.name)
```

I didn't find the right attribute in Discord API.
What attribute should I use to delete the channel in which I wrote the command?
`Error: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'delete_text_channel'`

Comment: Aside from previous errors, you need to call `delete` on a TextChannel object https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.delete

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak Any subclass of [`GuildChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) has its corresponding [`delete` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete). This includes [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel) and [`CategoryChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel).

Comment: @Harmon758 and? `delete_text_channel` and `discord.TextChannel` were enough of a hint for me to tell me that he's dealing with TextChannel. But I get your point altho I'm not sure comments are the best place to get into details. It was more of a hint from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`GuildChannel.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete) method, with any subclass of [`GuildChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel).
You can retrieve the [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) the message was sent in using [`Context.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel).

You should not be modifying the attributes of discord.py classes, and you should be referencing the attributes of specific objects/instances of those classes.

Answer (score 2):

@Harmon758 gives a very good idea of how the delete command should be called but for anyone not familiar with discord API, here is how I handle delete channel request:

```
@bot.command(name='delete-channel', help='delete a channel with the specified name')
async def delete_channel(ctx, channel_name):
   # check if the channel exists
   existing_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=channel_name)
   
   # if the channel exists
   if existing_channel is not None:
      await existing_channel.delete()
   # if the channel does not exist, inform the user
   else:
      await ctx.send(f'No channel named, "{channel_name}", was found')
```