# How to delete the current channel of the command. Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a command that deletes the channel where it was run on.
My code is like this:

```
@client.command()
async def deletecurrent(ctx):
await ctx.send('Deleting..')
#Delete current channel code here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a Discord channel using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523537/how-to-delete-a-discord-channel-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even take the extra steps to get the current channel via the .get() method.

The current channel object is passed to you via the ctx object. It incorporates ctx.channel

So the code to delete the current channel would be:

```
await ctx.channel.delete()
```