# Discord doesn't delete channel

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    #new_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f"ticket-{message.author.name}")
    name = 'TICKETS'
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    foundchan = discord.utils.get(
        ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f"Ticket-{ctx.author.name}")
    if category is None:
        await ctx.guild.create_category(name)

    if foundchan is None:
        channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ctx.author.name}', category=category)
    if foundchan:
        await ctx.channel.send("ALREADY A  CHANNEL")
    Role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Ticket Support")
    if Role is None:
        await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Ticket Support")
    else:
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.author, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, view_channel=True)
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, view_channel=False)
        await channel.set_permissions(Role, view_channel=True, send_messages=True, add_reactions=True)
        await channel.send(f"Hey, {ctx.author.mention}, thank you for creating a ticket; please be patient untill one of our staff member to come.")
        await channel.send("**Say '*close' to close the ticket.**")


@client.command()
async def close(ctx):
    foundchan = discord.utils.get(
        ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f"ticket-{ctx.author.name}")
    # await discord.Member.send(f"Your ticket was closed by {ctx.author.name}")
    await foundchan.delete()
#Here is the full code everything is working but when i try to delete the channel it doesnt work and give me this error  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

I need help it gives me this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'

a help would be really appreciated cause its been so long and i cant find out the solution, tysm for everything

Comment: That error means that `foundchan` is empty, i was looking for `guild.text_channels` api in the documentation, where did you find that, can you link some source for that.

Comment: i made it myself

Comment: I suspect there is the problem then. Can you also add that part in your question.

Comment: Do you have discord or something i cant say it in here too long

Comment: There i edited it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523537/how-to-delete-a-discord-channel-using-python This might be of some help

Comment: I don't understand it can you like reedit the thing i should be modifying?

Comment: can you try it with `ctx.guild.channels` rather than text_channel?

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete' I still get it

Comment: I have added an answer. See if that works out.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64282450/7116645

Taking reference from above answer and modifying it for your code.
You can try following code:

```py
@client.command()
async def close(ctx):
    foundchan = discord.utils.get(
        ctx.guild.channels, name=f"ticket-{ctx.author.name}")
    # await discord.Member.send(f"Your ticket was closed by {ctx.author.name}")
    if foundchan is not None:
        await foundchan.delete()
    else:
        print("No channel exist by that Name")
```

There is another version which you can try

```py
@client.command()
async def close(ctx):
    foundchan = discord.utils.get(
        ctx.all_channels(), guild__name=ctx.guild, name=f"ticket-{ctx.author.name}")
    # await discord.Member.send(f"Your ticket was closed by {ctx.author.name}")
    if foundchan is not None:
        await foundchan.delete()
    else:
        print("No such channel")
```

And of course, make sure that channel exists!

Comment: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'all_channels'

Comment: It keeps printing no such a channel